# How to handle expection raised from CURSOR declaration

Tags: plsql

So I have a procedure below that accept a date as an IN parameter. If a wrong type of parameter is passed in, the exception area will not be able to catch it because the parameter is used in the CURSOR declaration section.

```
PROCEDURE ABC(p_date IN DATE)
IS
  CURSTOR cur
  IS 
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE table.date = TRUNC(p_date);
BEGIN
do something;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
   do something;
END;
```

If the user passes a wrong parameter type:

```
BEGIN
ABC(123);
END;
```

I'll get the "wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ABC'" error.

Is there a way to handle this error under this scenario?

Comment: the error appears not in the cursor, but while calling the procedure. Your proc accepts a DATE but you pass a NUMBER to it. Conversion Number->Date fails - hence the error

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean if a wrong parameter is passed, there's no way to handle the exception?

Comment: It doesn't. You could always handle the exception where the procedure is called.

Answer (score 0):

Micklesh is correct.  An error in calling the procedure isn't handled by the called procedure, it needs to be handled in the calling procedure.